# REGEX "dynamic" substitution

Tags: python, regex

I have a **multi-line string** and need to append at the beginning of each row a (varying) character (1 white-space as separator). How can I do that with regex? Is there a way to do that without without too many splittings and merging?

It is assumed that the amount of rows is equal to the amount of characters to be added.

Input

```
m = """
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 1 1 2 3 4
"""
```

Desired output (assumed reference string `"bip"`)

```
b 0 1 2 3 4 5
i 1 0 1 2 3 4
p 2 1 1 2 3 4
```

Here an example of working code based on `\n` match

```
import re

m = """
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 1 1 2 3 4
"""

re.sub(r'\n', '\n{} ', m[:-1]).format(*list('bip'))
```

but I needed to omit the last character, it would `\n`. I tried to play around with other pattern such as `\A` or `\^` or `^`, `flags=re.MULTILINE` but with no success.

How can I avoid the string slice `m[:-1]`?

Is there a more **pure** regex way to solve the problem?

Comment: No, this is not possible with pure regex.

Comment: Are you after https://ideone.com/H1d40q?

Comment: Ok thanks... it is a relief. And, in this example, so do you have a suggestion for a different pattern to avoid the string slice?

Comment: Note in your current `m` string, the first and last empty lines are introduced, if you use `m.strip()` the code in my previous comment will work. See https://ideone.com/jODUkJ

Comment: May be: `repl = 'bip'` and `re.sub(r'\n', '\n{} ', m, len(repl)).format(*list(repl))`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew yes, you got it! Thanks for the strip() hint! You can post it as an answer

Comment: @anubhava I got a strange output, not even rectangular

Comment: `print (re.sub(r'\n', '\n{} ', m, len(repl)).format(*list(repl)))` works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply `.strip()` to your `m` string, you can use

```py
import re
m = """
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 1 1 2 3 4
"""
print(re.sub(r'^', '{} ', m.strip(), flags=re.M).format(*list('bip')))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/jODUkJ), the output will be

```py
b 0 1 2 3 4 5
i 1 0 1 2 3 4
p 2 1 1 2 3 4
```

The `^` regex anchor will match any line start position since the `flags` argument is set to `re.M` (equivalent to `re.MULTILINE`).

Answer (score 5):

Here is another approach [using 4th parameter `count` of `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) that tells how many substitutions are to be made:

As per linked doc:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

**Code:**

```sh
import re
 
m = """
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 1 1 2 3 4
"""
repl = 'bip'
 
print (re.sub(r'\n', '\n{} ', m, len(repl)).format(*list(repl)))

# or use this if you want to strip leading and trailing newlines
# print (re.sub(r'\n', '\n{} ', m, len(repl)).format(*list(repl)).strip())
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/FM0i8L)

**Output:**

```
b 0 1 2 3 4 5
i 1 0 1 2 3 4
p 2 1 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: yes, it works now! my mistake. Could you also write the key of the 4th parameter of sub and what is about?

Comment: Have added link to official doc as well

Comment: Thanks, nice approach as well